# Paypal Integration basic level Knowledge Step by Step manner like Algorithm to integrate

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am student and just started coding using ASP.NET C# and Familiar with MVC.
My final year college project is online shopping in which I wanted to integrate **"Paypal"** and for that I search everywhere but I don't get the starting point of it.
Please guide me in a step by step manner regarding paypal integration so that I can successfully create it.As a summary like an algorithm where things are mentioned in step by step manner I need that.

Comment: First of all you gotta know there are many PayPal products: Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments, Payments Starndard, Button Manager, etc, etc, etc... which one is the one you need? OR what is the use case?

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for Response I wanted to use "Express Checkout" since I don't have any Internet Merchant Account.

Comment: Thank you sir for your prompt concern I wanted to use "Classic API".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link is the perfect explanation of my query:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal